# Ordenar boxplot por media en R - error

Tags: r

Estoy intentando ordenar mis datos en un gráfico boxplot en R, por la media, pero en el último paso me da error. Abajo copio el script y el error. Gracias:

```
>Tempranillo <- read.table("/Users/davidgramaje/Desktop/Tempranillo_def.csv", header=T, sep=",")

> attach(Tempranillo)

> names (Tempranillo)
[1] "CLON"   "LESION"

> quantile(LESION, probs=c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))
     0%     25%     50%     75%    100% 
  0.000   8.000  13.811  26.000 177.183 

> boxplot (LESION~CLON, Tempranillo)

> spray2 <- with(Tempranillo, factor(CLON, levels=levels(CLON)[order(tapply(LESION,CLON,median))]))

> boxplot(LESION~spray2, Tempranillo)
```

> Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response], drop = drop,  : 
>     invalid first argument

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido. Para asegurarte una buena respuesta te sugiero que incluyas un ejemplos breve de los datos en la pregunta. Podrías pegar en tu pregunta la salida de dput(head(Tempranillo)). Si no puedes hacer públicos los datos podrías crear unos aleatorios con estructura similar. Puedes editar tu propia pregunta para agregarlo. Saludos!

Comment: Hola, esto es lo que me sale después de la salida que indicas:structure(list(CLON = c(36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L), LESION = c(66, 
14, 24, 6, 8, 24)), .Names = c("CLON", "LESION"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: He cambiado la variable numérica CLON por nombres y ahora me funciona bien...

Comment: ¿Pudiste resolverlo correctamente?

Comment: si! todo correcto

Comment: Votando por cerrar como error tipográfico/no reproducible basado en el comentario del autor